# Extracting outputs from a multiprocessed python function

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am wondering how to extract outputs from a multiprocessed function in Python. I am new to multiprocessing and have limited understanding of how it all works (not for lack of trying though).

I need to run the optimization with 31 different inputs for InfForecast and InitialStorage (for now... could be up to 10,000 inputs and independent optimizations being performed). I was hoping I could speed things up using multiprocessing to process more than one of these independent optimizations at a time. What I want is for the outputs (5 values for each optimization) to be put into the array "Nextday" which should have dimensions of (5,31). It seems the output Nextday as I've got the code written is either empty or not accessible. How do I extract/access the values and place them into Nextday?

*Note: The function main(...) is a highly complex optimization problem. I hope the problem is easy enough to understand without providing it. It works when I loop over it and call it for each i in range(31).*

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
Nextday=np.zeros((5,31))
pool_size = 4  # Should I set this to the number of cores my machine has?
pool = Pool(pool_size)

def optimizer(InfForecast, InitialStorage):
    O=main(InfForecast,InitialStorage)        
    return [O[0][0], O[0][1], O[0][2], O[0][3], O[0][4]] 


for i in range(31):
    pool.apply_async(optimizer, (InfForecast[i],InitialStorage[i]))

pool.close()
Nextday=pool.join()
```

In addition to this, I'm not sure whether this is the best way to do things. If it's working (which I'm not sure it is) it sure seems slow. I was reading that it may be better to do multiprocessing vs threading and this seems to be threading? Forgive me if I'm wrong.

I am also curious about how to select pool_size as you can see in my comment in the code. I may be running this on a cloud server eventually, so I expect the pool_size I would want to use there would be slightly different than the number I will be using on my own machine. Is it just the number of cores?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at pool.map?

Comment: I have looked at the documentation but it's all kind of over my head. I'm pretty new to programming. It's not clear to me how to use it for my particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
```

if you want to do multiprocessing.

Pool size should start out as `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` if you have the machine to yourself, and adjusted manually for best effect. If your processes are cpu-bound, then leaving a core available will make your machine more responsive -- if your code is not cpu-bound you can have more processes than cores (tuning this is finicky though, you'll just have to try).

You shouldn't have any code at the top-most level in your file when doing multiprocessing (or any other time really). Put everything in functions and call the start function from:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     my_start_function()
```

(digression: using capital oh as a variable name is really bad, and you get statements that are almost unreadable in certain fonts like O[0][0]).

In regular python, the `map` function is "defined" by this equality:

```
map(fn, lst) == [fn(item) for item in lst]
```

so the Pool methods (imap/imap_unordered/map/map_async) has similar semantics, and in your case you would call them like:

```
def my_start_function():
    ...
    results = pool.map(optimizer, zip(InfForecast, InitialStorage))
```

Since the map-functions take a function and a list, I've used the `zip` function to creates a list where each item has one element from each of its arguments (it functions as like a zipper).

Comment: Thanks @thebjorn. What if InfForecast is an array and InitialStorage is a float? Will I be able to zip things with different dimensions? There are also many additional arguments that don't change from optimization to optimization which I took out for the simplification of the example.

Comment: Look at the functions in the `itertools` module if you want to continue using zip, but you can create the arguments list any way you want to. Just remember that the second argument to map is a list, where each element contains the arguments for one invocation of the function.

Comment: How would I go about creating, say, 30 invocations of the function with 30 different "InfForecast" arrays where everything else stays the same?

Comment: Instead of the zip, use something like `[(fcast, other, arguments) for fcast in InfForecast]`

Comment: That seems to work. Now I need to figure out how to get the results back onto a single CPU and use them. If I keep them on multiple CPU's, I have issues with the permissions of files I'm accessing (it says they are "busy" or have "insufficient permissions"), presumably because it is trying to access the files from each CPU? Any idea how to close the pool and return the results to my primary CPU?

Comment: Assuming that you call `my_start_function()` from your primary CPU, then the results are automatically collected for you and placed in the `results` variable :-)